# Difference between dates from Database in another location and client's local time

Tags: date, timestamp

I have a requirement to disregard records from the DB that are more than 10 minutes old. However, the DB server is present in a different time zone than the app server. I tried to leverage the time zone details from the timestamp column value but it seems that they do not store the time zone details in that column value (bad design?). However, i have found a way to get this information for the DB instance using a query:

```
select dbtimezone from dual.
```

However, most of the implementations in java support time zones via names and not offset information. I need to be able to translate this offset exactly to a timezone (EST etc) so that i may not miss any DST related time in my calculations. like so:

```
TimeZone dbZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(10000); // offset is +10000

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(dbZone);
cal.setTime(new Date());

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(dbZone);
Date parsedDate = df.parse(df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

The plan is to convert the present client/app time to the DB specific timezone time and perform the difference between the two.

This cannot be done in a query due to some restraints. Please do not ask me to write a query to get latest records etc. Must be done in Java.

Any tips?

Comment: You should add "Java" as a tag to your question and a word in your title, for clarity. Otherwise this looks like a SQL question.

Comment: How is the date-time stored on the records? What data type, what database engine? The time zone of the database server should be irrelevant as a proper database stores date-times in UTC (no time zone offset).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it might get you in the right direction. You can try the following so you know the offset from EST and can do the calculation accordingly:

```
SELECT TZ_OFFSET('US/Eastern') FROM DUAL;
```

So a return of -3:00 would mean it is PST time. Maybe you've already tried this?